# service to port number like getaddrinfo

Tags: c, service, port, getaddrinfo

In C you can use a service name to get the port number when using getaddrinfo, like this:

```
getaddrinfo("stackoverflow.com", "http", &hints, &results);
```

This will assign 80 (big endian) to the first two bytes (uint16_t) of results->ai_addr.

Is there some easy way to get the port number from ?only? giving the service name? I need this for the server side, where I want to allow the user to specify either port number or service name for the port to bind and listen to.

Comment: `grep -w http /etc/services`?

Comment: @alk that is a good idea, but is there some standard C function for this?

Comment: No, as well as `getaddrinfo()` isn't Standard C.

Comment: How you want make a server listen on a "*service name*", btw?

Comment: @alk You are right, but it's from a rather common linux library to use when working with sockets. Is there something comparable?

Comment: @alk Bind a sockaddr, containing the port, to a socket, then listen.

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` is POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html

Comment: So what's the difference between "*port number*" and "*service name*" though?

Comment: @alk Service name is a char string and port number is big endian uint16_t.

Comment: I know, that's been the reason for the question in my 3rd comment. I get the impression there is a missunderstanding.

Comment: I got you now: "*... be specified ...*" is meant to be "*... be specified by the user ...*" and not "*... be specified to bind() ...*"

Comment: @alk I don't where my head was when I wrote that last sentence. I think I've fixed it now. lol

Comment: "*Is there something comparable?*" Where? In the C Standard? Comparable to what?

Comment: :-) The more precise the question, the more precices the anwers.

Comment: @alk A function in a library comparable, comparable as in as commonly used and as related as possible, to the one getaddrinfo is in.

Comment: The C Standard does not cover networking.

Comment: @alk I said a standard c function, not the C standard library. Obviously bad wording on my part, but I meant a commonly used function/library that is pretty much the standard to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `getaddrinfo` with a null pointer for the hostname and `AI_PASSIVE` in the flags will give you a `sockaddr` you can bind on for running a server. See the documentation for `getaddrinfo`:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html

Answer (score 0):

man getservbyname

```
  #include \netdb.h>
   struct servent *getservent(void);
   struct servent *getservbyname(const char *name, const char *proto);
   struct servent *getservbyport(int port, const char *proto);
```

Comment: Still POSIX, 1+ however.

Comment: @alk Do notice I never say in the question it needs to be from the standard C library. In fact, I mention getaddrinfo, which isn't in the standard C library. When I in the comment said some standard C function for this, I meant more as in a commonly used C function/library that is pretty much the standard to use, but I get the confusion.

Comment: This is outdated/deprecated and non-thread-safe. The correct way is `getaddrinfo`.